# Конвертер PNG\GIF\JPG в ICO

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Нужен скрипт конвертации PNG\GIF\JPG в ICO!

Язык: PHP

Comment: @guligi, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/chrisbliss18/php-ico)

Также [Imagic](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick):
пример
http://www.phpro.org/examples/Create-Favicon-With-Imagick.html

Comment: Если я хорошо помню, то на сервер сперва загружаются файлы во временное хранишище. А потом вы скриптом можете их двигать, куда нужно.
Наверное, я не понял вопроса. Но я бы сделал загрузку в какую-нибудь папку, а файлы бы хоранял с уникальным именем, помнил бы его на пртяжении работы скрипта. А после скачивания удалял бы.

Comment: @guligi, не надо ничего под одним именем хранить, надо просто после конвертации / по истечении какого-то срока файлы удалять.